# TCP buffering on read

Tags: sockets, tcp

I want to reduce the latency of a TCP server. So I read about, and used TCP_NODELAY. Great! overall latency went down a bit! Now I'm thinking that I can probably also reduce latency when reading. But I don't understand very well the behavior of the TCP stack. What happens for example in the following code in the receiver side, if the sender sends a packet of just 25 bytes?

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
received = read (common_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

My particular question is, if the socket is blocking, when the call to read will return? Are there any cases when TCP will wait a little bit for more data to arrive before a return from the read call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the socket is blocking, when the call to read will return?

If there is data in the socket receive buffer or a pending end-of-stream or error it will return immediately, otherwise it will block, *once*, until one of those conditions occurs.

> Are there any cases when TCP will wait a little bit for more data to arrive before a return from the read call?

No.

Comment: actually answer to 2 is YES if you didn't set Nagle's TCP_NODELAY. Even with this bit set, the OS tcp stack implementation is free to wait for additional data before calling you back with it. I for sure saw cases where this happened. Should you want to really speed up things, you need to do everything in user space with dedicated network cards, such as the SolarFlare ones.

Comment: @dau_sama Now I'm confused!!

Comment: read upon how tcp works, there is more than just Nagle algorithm, and it is a quite  complex protocol. For your purpose, unless you need really low latency, what you have should be enough. If you want to achieve nanoseconds performance, that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

read is a blocking call, that means it will block at the read line until you'll receive something.

If you receive less than your buffer size, you'll move to the next operation and your "received" variable will hold the number of bytes that have been read.

reference:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is
>   not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
>   actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-
>   file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or
>   because read() was interrupted by a signal.  On error, -1 is
>   returned, and errno is set appropriately.  In this case, it is left
>   unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm concerned about any buffering tricks that  TCP may have. Please check my edit.